# Twitter Typeahead in CodeIgniter. Not passing array datum to hidden form field

Tags: php, codeigniter, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use the typeahead.js Twitter Typeahead (not Bootstrap typeahead) to display names pulled from a mysql table using the CodeIgniter framework.  The model also collects id values along with the name.

The controller and model seem to be presenting the correct array format.

**Model**

```
class People_model extends CI_Model{

   function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
   }
    function get_person($name) {
        $mode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->db->select("id, CONCAT(firstName,' ', lastName) AS name, type",FALSE);
        $this->db->from('people');
        if($mode == 'signin')
            $this->db->where("status !=", "enter");
        else
            $this->db->where("status", "enter");
        $this->db->like("concat(firstName,' ', lastName)", $name);
        $this->db->order_by('name');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
            $new_row['id']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
            $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

**Controller** (relevant functions)

```
    function get_person() {
        $this->config->set_item('disable_template', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('People_model');
        $name = $this->input->get_post();
        $this->People_model->get_person($name); 
    }

    function dosigninout() {
        $mode = $this->uri->segment(3);
        switch($mode) {
            case 'signin':
                $mode = 'enter';
                break;
            case 'signout':
                $mode = 'exit';
                break;
            default:
                $this->load->view("home/error", array('error' => "Invalid mode specified."));
        }
        $meeting = $this->_currentMeeting();
        $person = $this->input->post('person_id');    
        if(!$this->_validPerson($person, $this->input->post('name'))) $this->load->view("home/error", array('error' => "You requested an operation with ".$this->input->post('name')." who has an ID of $person. The name and ID don't match."));

        $this->db->insert("attendance", array('person_id' => $person, 'meeting_id' => $meeting['meetingID'], 'type' => $mode));
        $this->db->where("id", $person);
        $this->db->update("people", array('status' => $mode));
        $redirectTo = (isset($_POST['redirect'])) ? $this->input->post('redirect') : false;
        if($redirectTo) redirect($redirectTo);
        else redirect('attendance');
    }
```

**Sample JSON data returned**

```
[{"value":"Anna Woodhouse","id":"2"},{"value":"Elaine Woodhouse","id":"4"}]
```

**View**

```
$baseURL = base_url();
$extraHeadData = "";

?>
<h2><?=$title?></h2>
<p>Current meeting: <?=$meetingTitle?> on <?=$meetingDate?>.</p>
<?=form_open("attendance/dosigninout/$mode", array('id' => "signInOutForm"))?>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Whom do you want to sign <?=($mode == "signin") ? 'in' : 'out'?>?</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="hidden" name="person_id" id="person_id" value="" />
                <input class="people-typeahead" type="text" id="typeahead" name="name" placeholder="person's full name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <?=form_submit('','Save changes','class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
        </div>
</form>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo $baseURL?>assets/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function($) {
    $('input.people-typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'people',                                                             
        remote: 'http://localhost/badgeentry/index.php/attendance/get_person',
        dataType: 'json'                                                                        
    });
    $("#people-typeahead").on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function(e,datum) { 
        $(person_id).val() = datum.id
        });
});
</script>
```

In the form field I get the correct drop down list, but when an item is selected any new database entry has an id of "0" instead of the selected name id.  I'm almost certain that this is an issue with the javascript code in the view not being correct, but quite frankly, I have no js skills to sort it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get this working.  Part of the problem was that I could find no examples of using typeahead.js in CodeIgniter that showed how the various script, view, controller and model components interact.  I tried switching to Twitter bootstrap typeahead. However, despite finding references to using it with an arrays rather than a string, I still could not get a working solution.

In the end I went back to Twitter typeahead and started from scratch.  I found this tutorial helped enormously:

[Twitter Bootstrap typeahead.js with underscore.js Templating – A Tutorial - Alan Greenblatt](http://blattchat.com/2013/06/04/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-js-with-underscore-js-tutorial/)

I'm posting what worked for me in case it can help anyone else with similar issues.  This version also includes setting the remote source as a variable which allowed me to define it through PHP so that I could select data in the model based on the URL.

**Model**

```
class People_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
function get_person($name) {
    $modeinout = $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $this->db->select("id, CONCAT(firstName,' ', lastName) AS name, type",FALSE);
    $this->db->from('people');
    if($modeinout == 'signin'){
        $this->db->where('status !=', 'enter');
    }        
    else {
        $this->db->where('status', 'enter');
    }       
    $this->db->like("concat(firstName,' ', lastName)", $name);
    $this->db->order_by('name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $new_row['name']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
            $new_row['id']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
            $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
}
```

**Controller** (relevant functions)

```
function signin() {
    $this->load->helper("form");
    $this->template->javascript('assets/js/underscore-min.js');
    $this->template->javascript('assets/js/typeahead.min.js');
    $data = $this->_currentMeeting();
    $data['title'] = "Sign Someone In";
    $data['attributes_form'] = array('id' => 'signInOutForm','class' => 'form-horizontal validate', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data');
    $data['mode'] = 'signin';
    $this->load->view("home/attendance/signinout", $data);
    }   

function signout() {
    $this->load->helper("form");
    $this->template->javascript('assets/js/underscore-min.js');
    $this->template->javascript('assets/js/typeahead.min.js');
    $data = $this->_currentMeeting();
    $data['attributes_form'] = array('id' => 'signInOutForm','class' => 'form-horizontal validate', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data');
    $data['id'] = '';
    $data['title'] = "Sign Someone Out";
    $data['mode'] = 'signout';
    $this->load->view("home/attendance/signinout", $data);

}
function get_people() {
    $this->config->set_item('disable_template', TRUE);
    $this->load->model('People_model');
    $name = $this->input->post('query');
    $this->People_model->get_person($name);
}

function dosigninout() {
    $mode = $this->uri->segment(3);
    switch($mode) {
        case 'signin':
            $mode = 'enter';
            break;
        case 'signout':
            $mode = 'exit';
            break;
        default:
            $this->load->view("home/error", array('error' => "Invalid mode specified."));
    }
    $meeting = $this->_currentMeeting();
    $person = $this->input->post('person_id');
    if(!$this->_validPerson($person, $this->input->post('person_name'))) $this->load->view("home/error", array('error' => "You requested an operation with ".$this->input->post('person_name')." who has an ID of $person. The name and ID don't match."));
    $this->db->insert("attendance", array('person_id' => $person, 'meeting_id' =>      $meeting['meetingID'], 'type' => $mode));
    $this->db->where("id", $person);
    $this->db->update("people", array('status' => $mode));
    $redirectTo = (isset($_POST['redirect'])) ? $this->input->post('redirect') : false;
    if($redirectTo) redirect($redirectTo);
    else redirect('attendance');
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
$baseURL = base_url();
$extraHeadData = "";

?>
<h2><?=$title?></h2>
<p>Current meeting: <?=$meetingTitle?> on <?=$meetingDate?>.</p>
<?=form_open("attendance/dosigninout/$mode", array('id' => "signInOutForm",'class' => "form-horizontal validate"))?>
<input type="hidden" name="person_id" id="person_id">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Whom do you want to sign <?=($mode == "signin") ? 'in' : 'out'?>?</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="person's full name" name="person_name" id="person_name" class="person-typeahead">
            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <?=form_submit('','Save changes','class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
        </div>
</form>   
<script>
    var person_url="<?php echo site_url('attendance/get_people')."/".$mode;?>";
   $(function($) {    
      _.compile = function(templ) {
         var compiled = this.template(templ);
         compiled.render = function(ctx) {
            return this(ctx);
         }
         return compiled;
      }
      $('.person-typeahead').typeahead({
         template: '<p><strong><%= name %></strong>:&nbsp;<%= id %></p>',
         name: 'people',
         valueKey: 'name',
         engine: _,
         remote: (person_url),
         dataType: 'json'
      }).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(event, datum) {
         $('#person_id').val(datum.id);
         $('#person_name').val(datum.name);


        });
   });
</script>
<?=jquery_validate('attendance/signout');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue here :

```
        $(person_id).val() = datum.id
```

You are using jQuery's .val() incorrectly and the use of the selector is wrong too. It should look like :

```
$("#person_id").val(datum.id);
```

[jQuery .val() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: I tied this with $('#person_id').val(datum.id); and $('#person_name').val(datum.name); but they did not help.  The line I used above was taken from a typeahead.js GitHub issue posting.

Comment: Your answer was part of the solution though.  See my own answer below.